# Return own static value in Observable

Tags: node.js, typescript, observable, axios, nestjs

In my nest.js project I do a get request to a open API. If there is no result from the API I get HTTP Status 400. In that case I want to return a empty static object from the `Observable`.

```
this.getData(data.title)
         .subscribe((resp) => {
             console.log(resp);
         });
```

Observable

```
getData(title: string){
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(API.TOKEN);
    const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr }
      };
    const emptyResponse = {
        "data": [{"id": ''}]
    }
    try {
        return this.httpService.get(API.ID_URL + title, requestOptions);
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.response.status == 400){
            return of(JSON.stringify(emptyResponse)); //this doesn't work
        }
        this.errorHandling(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Observables`, you have to use the `catchError` operator instead of try/catch:

```
this.httpService.get(API.ID_URL + title, requestOptions)
  .pipe(catchError(err => {
    if (err.response && err.response.status == 400) {
      return of({});
    } else {
      this.errorHandling(err);
    }
  }));
```

---

Alternatively, you can transform the `Observable` to a `Promise`. With async/await you can then use try/catch:

```
async getData(title: string) {
^^^^^
  // ...
  try {
      return await this.httpService.get(API.ID_URL + title, requestOptions).toPromise();
             ^^^^^                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  } catch (error) {
      if(error.response.status == 400){
          return emptyResponse;
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }
      this.errorHandling(error);
  }
```

Note that `getData` now returns a `Promise` and not an `Observable` so you have to change the places where the method gets called.